# How is disk cluster/block size relevant for binary file reading?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have some very big binary files (>1TB each) with highly compressed data. I read very often some data chunks of about 300 bytes from these files. To do that I have the file opened in 7 threads at once and do read operations.

How does the disk cluster size correspond to this. When I read 300 bytes and the disk cluster size is set to 64KB, will .net read the whole 64KB instead the 300 bytes?

Is a small or a big cluster size better for this scenario?
I use FileStream with FileOptions set to FileOptions.RandomAccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will read 64kb chunks off the disk. A smaller cluster size will provide you faster reads of small ranges. It has the risk of more file fragmentation (probably not a concern).

You can't get much more throughput, though, by lowering the cluster size. In the time the disk has done the seek operation do get your data it could have read about 1MB of data. You are saving very little by going from 64kb to 4kb. You are saving about 1/20th of the time the disk seek took.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to optimize your buffer size for reads from any given partition at runtime, you can go a step further and get the cluster size at runtime and use a multiple of that for your read buffer.

However, you will need to PInvoke from kernel32.dll to do this.

Use the GetDiskFreeSpace function to get cluster size for a given partition.

Here is the method signature:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
   static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpace(string lpRootPathName, 
   out uint lpSectorsPerCluster, 
   out uint lpBytesPerSector, 
   out uint lpNumberOfFreeClusters, 
   out uint lpTotalNumberOfClusters);
```

Pass it the path to the root of the drive you are interested in.
To get bytes per cluster, multiply lpSectorsPerCluster by lpBytesPerSector.

For more information, here's the pinvoke.com page on this function:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpace

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

The lower the cluster size, the lower the latency (delay), but also the lower the throughput (average data rate overall);

Comment: Lower throughput does not follow from a small cluster size at all.

Comment: @usr: Yes it does, because there is more overhead. (It's only really affects random reads than sequential reads though.)

Comment: The opposite is true: If there *was* an effect it would affect sequential operations more. The only two effects of small clusters are more allocation overhead and more fragmentation. Fragmentation hurts sequential, not random access.

Comment: @usr: You're right, what I said was wrong -- because what I *said* wasn't what I *meant*. When I said "random reads" I was referring to "random" from the *disk*'s perspective, not from the *file system*'s perspective. i.e. If your cluster sizes are smaller, then when your data is fragmented, the disk's random reads will get you less data per seek, and therefore that will hurt you. But I phrased it pretty poorly, I agree. :\